# VB-2008 How to retrieve strings with largest numerical suffix in an array?

Tags: vb.net

I got the following strings arrays

```
a.csv
a-1.csv
a-2.csv
a-3.csv
ab.csv
ab-1.csv
ab-2.csv
cccc.csv
cccc-1.csv
d.csv
```

In this strings arrays, it stores a series of test data, the naming conversion for each test data is  as follows,

`'unit name'+'-'+('suffix in single digit number')+'.csv'`

The length of the unit name could be any length, but the suffix can only be single-digit number (1-9). For example for unit `a`, it undergoes 4 test in total, which are `a.csv`, `a-1.csv`, `a-2.csv` and `a-3.csv`. But because all of the first three test fails the specs, therefore only the last test data will be retrieved for analysis, which is `a-3.csv`.

So, for the final output, I only need those data which have the largest suffix for each unit, which gives me the output string array:

```
a-3.csv
ab-2.csv
cccc-1.csv
d.csv
```

How should I choose the correct files from the input string array according to the rules to get those test data only got the largest suffix.

Comment: Could you please explain what it is that you're asking?

Comment: @DanDrews,the input is a string array, they are actually all the file names in the folder. You can treat them as a list of test data, a represents product a, b means product b, those a-1, a-2 are re-test data. So in the end i need to get the latest test data for each product, which are a-3, b-2, c-1, d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Function Suffix(ByVal s As String) As String
    s = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)
    Dim pos = s.LastIndexOf("-"c)
    Return If(pos = -1, s, s.Substring(0, pos))
End Function

Private Function Value(ByVal s As String) As Integer
    s = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s)
    Dim pos = s.LastIndexOf("-"c)
    Return If(pos = -1, 0, Integer.Parse(s.Substring(pos + 1)))
End Function
```

```
Dim arr() As String = New String() {"a.csv", "a-1.csv", "a-2.csv", "a-3.csv", "ab.csv", "ab-1.csv", "ab-2.csv", "cccc.csv", "cccc-1.csv", "d.csv"}

Dim largest = arr.GroupBy(Function(s) Suffix(s), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) _
                 .Select(Function(g) g.OrderByDescending(Function(s) Value(s)).First())

For Each s In largest
    Console.WriteLine(s)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Though your question is not clear but I think you want to have the latest occurrence to be stored in a separate array. Here is how you can achieve that:

```
    Dim arrayInput As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    arrayInput.Add("a.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("a-1.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("a-2.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("a-3.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("b.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("b-1.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("b-2.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("c.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("c-1.csv")
    arrayInput.Add("d.csv")

    Dim arrayOutput As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Dim strTemp As String = arrayInput(0)
    Dim startingChar As String = strTemp.Substring(0, 1)

    For Each item As String In arrayInput
        If Not startingChar.Equals(item.Substring(0, 1), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            arrayOutput.Add(strTemp)
            startingChar = item.Substring(0, 1)
        End If
        strTemp = item
    Next
    arrayOutput.Add(strTemp)
```

You have the required result in `arrayOutput`. Let me know if you wanted something else instead.

Comment: Thanks very much,@AhmedSalmanTahir,  you pretty much got what i mean. I ran your code and it did work. But one problem is that for the final output, I only need the strings with the largest suffix, such as for inputs a-1, a-2, a-3. The output will be a-3(since 3>2>1). But your code is to get the latest occurrence. Sorry that I didn't make it clear.

Comment: What if you sort your array in ascending order before applying my logic? Wouldn't it mean that the one with highest suffix always comes at the end?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that i don't know how to sort.. And one more thing is that my string doesn't always starts with just one character, in my example I use 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'. But it could also be 'aa', 'aaa'.

Comment: Here is the statement for sorting 'arrayInput.Sort()' This will also take care of the single/multiple character scenario. However, there will be a problem: if you have a, a-1 up to say a-10, then it will sort like a, a-1, a-10, a-2, a-3, a-4 and so on

Comment: is there a way that it can sort like a, a-1, a-2, a-3, a-10, just like  in windows "sort by name"